# "Фраза" в смысле "предложение"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Нормально ли использовать слово "фраза" в значении "предложение"? Естественно, это не означает, что у слова "фраза" нет другого значения, но можно ли вкладывать в это слово такой смысл тоже? Насколько это корректно при общении на данном сайте пренебрегать разницей в значениях, даже если она есть?

Поясню получше, что речь идёт только о том случае, когда вместо слова "предложение" хочется сказать более короткое и простое слово "фраза", а не о том, чтобы вообще не применять это слово ни в каком значении.

Comment: Почему всё-таки так с падежом? Долго колебался и менял туда-сюда.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova, Галина, может, Вы всё-таки ответите теперь на этот вопрос про падеж (почему Вы исправили Я на Е)? Я понимаю, что Вы, видимо, просто не увидели тогда моего комментария, не было у Вас уведомления. А то очень интересно разобраться, чем родительный плох.

Comment: Тёмыч, может я и не права - просто резануло глаз. Нечто одно в значении нечта другого...

Comment: *Нечто одно в значении нечта другого.* Ну да, только мне казалось, так нормально. Надо спросить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нормально! Первое из лексических значений слова "[фраза](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0)" -

> отрезок речи, относительно самостоятельный в смысловом и интонационном
>   отношении (обычно сопровождается паузой).

Лингвисты спорят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но почему тогда не напишут "то же, что предложение" или хотя бы "в том числе абсолютно идентичное "предложению" значение"?

Comment: Тогда надо идти через предложение к сообщению, затем к высказыванию... *ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ. Лингв. Высказывание, являющееся сообщением о чём-л."* Так мы закольцуемся. 8-(

Comment: Я добавила в ответ хорошенькую ссылочку: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1798/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0 - пятёрку поставь!

Comment: Такое впечатление, что некоторые господа учёные сочиняли свои определения единственно во имя самоутверждения. Особенно это касается случаев отождествления фразы с предложением - терминологически это бесполезно: смешивая понятия, утрачивают нужное для разграничения слово. Куда лучше закрепить слово "фраза" за меньшей единицей, чтобы выбором термина отличать одно от другого.

Comment: Для того, чтобы назвать словосочетание из двух или более слов фразой (которая вовсе не обязана выражать законченную мысль - это тоже ненужная химера), на мой взгляд, достаточно наличия глагола (он устанавливает связь между частями самой фразы). Например, "убить пересмешника" я называю фразой, но не предложением; можно оформить её как неполное предложение (напр. в виде ответной реплики), но вне контекста она не будет иметь законченного смысла.

Comment: Цитата - из Линвистического словаря, она объективно собрала точки зрения именитых филологов. А автор вопроса волен определять, что именно ему по душе.