# Что-то в смысле чего-то, падеж

Tags: падежи

В [этом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420089/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment431703_420089) вопросе у меня был заголовок «"*фраза*" в смысле "*предложения*"», но Галина (ещё давно) исправила на "предложени**е**", то есть родительный на именительный падеж.

Как всё-таки правильно? Или, может, можно и так, и так? Хотя мне именительный падеж здесь кажется странным...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Галина права. Если в чем не права, то только в том, что не пояснила (хотя бы в комментариях) сделанную правку. Ну и возможно, "в смысле" стоило заменить  в заголовке на "в значении" (хотя это было бы уходом от авторского стиля, что далеко не всегда находит понимание).

Артем, давайте "от печки".

Людмила тоже права. Вся конструкция с учетом контекста выглядит странновато.
Поэтому и разобраться с пунктуацией непросто.

Думаю, что причина - в неудачном использовании оборота "в смысле".
Здесь надо бы *"Фраза" **в значении** "предложение"*.

Причем я вижу несколько разных варианта оформления в зависимости от смысла, включая "фантазийные" (один - как раз с кавычками и родительным падежом).

1. *"Фраза" в значении "предложение"*. Это вариант говорит о том, что термин **А** ("Фраза") где-то когда-то и кем-то использовался как синоним (полный или частичный) для термина **В** ("предложение"). По контексту видно, именно это вы и хотели сказать. Здесь нужен именно именительный, что легко понять запомнить: вы **называете** эти термины, даете им **имя**.
2. *[Эта] фраза в значении предложения*. Здесь говорится о том, что конкретная фраза априорно имеет значение предложения (а не просто называется так автором), что выделяет эту конкретную фразу из прочих, такого значения не имеющих.
3. *"Фраза" в значении предложения*. Некое предложение имеет определённое значение, и в нём есть слово "фраза".
4. *Фраза в значении "предложения"*.  Фраза (конкретная) использована для того, что названо "предложением". Это еще можно как-то понять, хотя уже с трудом.
5. *"Фраза" в значении "предложения"*. Нечто, именуемое "фраза", как-то соотносится со значением того, что скрыто под названием "предложение". Это не для простых умов, поверьте, и точно не то, что вы хотели сказать.

Наверное, это не всё. Но достаточно, думаю.

Если вы сделаете обратную замену "в значении" на более разговорное "в смысле", в принципе все те же варианты останутся, только разобраться с ними будет еще сложнее. Реальных тут два. №№ 1 и 2. Остальные - казуальны. Именно первые два и предлагается использовать для покрытия 99,999 % практических надобностей.

Я опускаю все варианты разбора, построенные на омонимичности форм (типа множественного числа и родительного единственного для слова "предложение").

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus! Только вот как ни старался, к сожалению, так и не понял с 3-го по 5-й пункты.(( Особенно 5-й жалко, п. ч. он такой, как я и хотел, но не такой по смыслу, как у меня (по вашим словам).

Comment: Ну знаете... ))) Совсем не поняли?

Comment: К сожалению, да, совсем... :( Попробую через несколько часов свежим взглядом на них посмотреть и перечитать. ;)

Comment: Теперь всё понял, слава Богу!) Просто такая формулировка в третьем: "значение, в котором". Я изменю для лучшего понимания, надеюсь, вы не против.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен контекст. Мне эта фраза вообще не нравится.

Думаю, корректно будет так: фраза в смысле (каком?) "предложение" - несогласованное определение, им. падеж.

Но: фраза в **значении** предложени**я**.

А лучше: фраза, т. е. предложение.

Comment: _Но: фраза в **значении** предложени**я**._ === Нет, лучше так: _Слово "фраза" в значении "предложение"._

Comment: Контекст по ссылке, Людмила. @slava1947, лучше именительный? Но почему?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: **Но почему?**_ === Хотя бы потому, что  Ваш вариант —   _«"фраза" в смысле "предложен**ия**"»_   —  неоднозначен в понимании.  Что в нём: родительный падеж ед. числа?  именительный падеж мн. числа?

Comment: Конечно, родительный единственного. Я же сравнивал родительный с именительным. Да, действительно неоднозначность... Но если был бы правильным только родительный, неоднозначности бы не было. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> В [**этом**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420089/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment431703_420089) вопросе у меня был заголовок *«"фраза" в смысле
>   "предложения"»*, но Галина (ещё давно) исправила на *"предложение"*,
>   то есть родительный на именительный падеж.

.

Галина была права. Нужен именительный падеж.

.

Ср. с примером у [**Розенталя**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169%D0%AE%D0%AE):

> **§ 59.**
>
> 1. Выделяются кавычками:
>
> <...>
>
> 7) слова, разъясняющие термины, выражения (***в значении… , в смысле…***
>   и т. п.):
>
> <...>
>
> *Хороший **в смысле «добрый»**...*

Comment: *Галина была права. Нужны кавычки и именительный падеж.* Ну, насчёт кавычек-то я и не сомневался. Спасибо за ответ!